# MySql Datatype INT clear itself after apply

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have issue with using MySql Datatype:INT type.

When i click apply button, all datatype:INT areas become empty. So i cannot use them in Foreign Keys section. Can you help me ??

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXu4y.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved with downgraded MySql server to 5.7